# Getting the results of a query c# - Access 2010

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, combobox

My database is in Access and it's connected to my Visual Studio C# project. I have this code here that gets info from a combobox (each case is the date of the weeks of a college semester). Since apparently I can't select the primary key if it's the values in the combobox, I've decided to use the dates as the values to select in the combobox and then use it to select the actual primary key in the database. Here's my code:

```
semSess = Convert.ToDateTime(comboSemSess.Text);

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection laConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            laComm = "SELECT NumeroSemaine FROM SemainDelaSession WHERE DebutSemaine = " + semSess +";";

            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(laComm, laConn);
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreur s'est produite en accédant à la base de données");
        }
```

This would get me the number of the week, say "1". What I can't figure out is how to get the value of NumeroSemaine out of myAccessCommand. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) for some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would go after "OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(laComm, laConn);"

```
OleDbDataReader reader = myAccessCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    //Logic goes here... each iteration is a row returned from the DB
    int numSemaine = Convert.toInt32(reader["NumeroSemaine"]); //now you have your value
}
```

Also dont forget to open your connection:

```
laConn.Open();
```